# Errors in Oracle procedure

Tags: sql, oracle

Simple procedure in Oracle does not work. Please help me figure out why.
NEWTABLE_TEST existing empty table with fields ID and COUNTER.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SDRG (ID IN VARCHAR2 (100), COUNTER IN NUMBER)
IS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO newtable_test (ID, COUNTER)
    SELECT doc.ID ID, doc.TPID COUNTER FROM A.doc
END SDRG;
```

Comment: "Not working" couldn't be more vague and meaningless. I guess you are after a MERGE rather than an INSERT. Please explain your use case. Help people here help you.

Comment: You are missing a `;` at the end of the penultimate line (after `FROM A.doc`) and the signature should not have a size on `VARCHAR2`. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5jNK4jON)

Comment: Your procedure parameters are never used. It would help if you explained what you expect the behaviour to be (in English, not code) because, apart from the couple of minor issues mentioned in the previous comment, your code would "work"; however, whether it will do what you expect is another matter as you do not explain what your expectations are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jason-shmeluavichus can you try below procedure and check :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SDRG (
  ID IN VARCHAR2,
  COUNTER IN NUMBER
) IS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO newtable_test (ID, COUNTER)
  SELECT doc.ID, doc.TPID
  FROM A.doc;
END SDRG;
```